# Specify dependency branch or commit ID in Swift PM's Package.swift

Tags: swift-package-manager

Is there a way to define dependency in `Package.swift` that would point at a certain branch latest commit, or even to just a specific commit ID (just like it is possible with Carthage)?

Use case would be, let's say I have a library repo where I would like to branch out and make some changes, and then be able to test them out in a dependent project.

Comment: It should be possible with buildMetadataIdentifiers. But I have had no luck so far.

Answer (score 10):

As of Swift 4 you can use `.branch()` and `.revision()` as described in [PackageDescription.md](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/PackageDescription.md).

Comment: Here is an example: 

.package(url: "https://github.com/somePackage", .branch("develop"))

Answer (score 7):

It is possible.

1. Go to project
2. Click on "Package Dependencies" Tab
3. Double click on the package you want to change the branch of
4. Specify the branch/commit.

[image: Choose branch or commit here]

Comment: In case of commit Xcode require us to specify the entire hash, not only the first 8 chars.

Answer (score 1):

Not yet, but swiftpm team is working on. Now you must specify a package version when declaring a dependency.

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Example",
    dependencies: [
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/somePackage", "1.0.0")
    ]
)
```

In the future it will be possible, there was a discussion to add [Version Locking](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-build-dev/Week-of-Mon-20160314/000343.html) but its not accepted and implemented yet.

For your use case you can fork the repo, do the changes, test them and then add a version tag to your fork. Now it's much more easier to do changes with [Editable Packages](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0082-swiftpm-package-edit.md) functionality.